# Syntax for nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, api, syntax, canvas-lms

I'm developing Python scripts for the automated grading of assignments using CanvasAPI, an API wrapper in Python for the Canvas learning management platform. In studying the documentation, I can successfully issue curl commands in Python for a few parameters. For example, this conversion below is for uploading rubric information for a single submission:

[Curl command per the Canvas API docs:](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/submissions.html#method.submissions_api.update)

```
PUT /api/v1/courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions/:user_id
```

with:

```
rubric_assessment[criterion_id][points]
```

[Turns into this via the CanvasAPI Python wrapper](https://canvasapi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/submission-ref.html#canvasapi.submission.Submission.edit)

```
edit(rubric_assessment={'criterion_#':{'points': 'point #'}})
```

However, I'm having difficulty with the syntax for adding additional parameters, which creates what appears to be nested dictionaries. For example, if I wanted to add a text comment along with grade points, the API documentation offers this:

```
rubric_assessment[criterion_id][comments]
```

For which I've attempted:

```
edit(rubric_assessment={'criterion_#':{'points': 'point #'}, {'criterion_#':{'comments': 'comment_text'}}})
```

which generates a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

I've also attempted:

```
edit(rubric_assessment={'criterion_#':{'points': 'point #'},{'comments': 'comment_text'}})
```

which generates this error:

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

What is the proper way to structure the syntax to pass both parameters? Many thanks for any insights and assistance.

Comment: You're trying to use dictionaries as dictionary keys, with no associated value.  You want something like `{a:b, c:d}`, or `{a:{b:c, c:d}, e:{f:g}}`.  But instead you have `{a:{b:c},{d:e}}`.  This last case is invalid for two reasons:  (1) It attempts to use `{d:e}` as a key, and (2) there is no value associated with the key.  Instead, you need something like `{a:{b:c},d:{e:f}}`, or `{a:{b:c,d:e}}`. Just remember not to use dictionaries as keys (in your case, your keys are strings), and to always follow your keys with `: value`, where `value` may or may not be a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from rubric_assessment[criterion_id][comments], it looks like you need,  `edit(rubric_assessment={'criterion_#':{'points': 'point #','comments':'comment_text'}})`